# how to keep the list view data in Fragment switch ?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I face a problem, I use tab style show different view, one view will push navigate in many other view that most like iOS UINavigationController, but seem Android no such feature at all, it is hard to handle this scene,

I have try some open source lib like: [cicerone](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone)

but it seem still can not solve my problem, maybe I miss some key function or property ?

any one help me ? thanks

Comment: try to use `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment. I usually put this code in `onCreate()` method of the `Fragment`. See more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Comment: thanks for guide.... I also found seem I need check the adapter , if I renew the adapter then the list data also can not be show ...

      if (null == adapter){
            adapter = new DataAdapter();
        }

       
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);